# Issue with a troublesome navigation bar (HTML and CSS)

Tags: css, html, navigationbar

I have a navigation bar on my homepage that has gone a bit wild. The final button link appears to have expanded below where it is meant to and it has also created a link out of the text I have underneath it. I would appreciate some help on this as I am not by any means a programmer and I am very new to the whole thing and I've most likely made a really obvious error (obvious to anyone but me, that is!). I have also changed any instance to where my real name is mentioned to 'Jon Snow' for obvious reasons and also just because.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<p>Jon Snow
Blah + A Student</p>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jonsnow.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactme.html">Contact Me</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="intro">
    <p>Hi, I'm Jon Snow, a student at Blah, University of Blah. This is my online portfolio!</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You changed your name to "Jon Snow" with the obvious reason that you are highly anticipating the return of GoT in the Spring?? :-p

Comment: You missed the closing tag </a> for `contactme`

Answer (score 1):

If this is a direct copy/paste from your web site, you need to close you last `<a>` tag within your `<li>` for "Contact Me

this tag:

```
 <li><a href="contactme.html">Contact Me</li>
```

Should be this:

```
<li><a href="contactme.html">Contact Me</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
<li><a href="contactme.html">Contact Me</li>
```

You have forgotten to close the `<a>` tag and this is causing your issue.

To correct it simply close the tag:

```
<li><a href="contactme.html">Contact Me</a></li>
```